# Convert a list of enums and store as 'varchar[]'

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, enums

Trying to figure out how to store a list of enums in a single table column.

I started with a `String` and it worked. I'll show only the relevant parts of the code:

```
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.ListArrayType;

...

@Entity
@TypeDefs({
    @TypeDef(
        name = "list-array",
        typeClass = ListArrayType.class
    )
})
@Table(name = "reports")
public class Reports {
...

    @Type( type = "list-array" )
    @Column(
        name = "origins",
        columnDefinition = "varchar[]",
        nullable = false
    )
    private List<String> origins;

...
```

The corresponding DDL of the column in PostgreSQL is defined as

```
origins _varchar NULL
```

In Liquibase script:

```
<column name="origins" type="varchar[]" remarks=""/>
```

However when I tried to store enums with the following changes to the code (I basically changed the type and the corresponding getters/setters)

```
private List<Origin> origins;
```

The enum code looks so:

```
public enum Origin {
 A, B, C
}
```

I got the error:

```
nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate Type: com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.ListArrayType
```

I also tried it with a converter but without success:

```
@Column(
        name = "origins",
        columnDefinition = "varchar[]",
        nullable = false
)
@Convert(converter = OriginConverter.class)
private List<Origin> origins;
```

The converter code is below:

```
@Converter
public class OriginConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<Origin>, List<String>> {

    @Override
    public List<String> convertToDatabaseColumn(List<Origin> origins) {
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        origins.forEach(
            origin -> values.add(origin.name())
        );
        return values;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Origin> convertToEntityAttribute(List<String> origins) {
        var values= origins.stream().map(Origin::valueOf).toList();
        return values;
    }
}
```

The error was:

```
could not insert...
...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unsupported Types value: 21,685,669
```

What am I missing?

Comment: [This blog](https://vladmihalcea.com/postgresql-array-java-list/) should be a good starting point. As you want to have `varchar[]`as database column, you would most probably need a converter in addition, to convert from enum to varchar and vice versa.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Yeah, it's so, but not quite clear how to combine them...
I ended up with still using the converter but which converts Set<Origin> to a String and uses comma as delimiter. The column type is just `varchar`

Comment: Why not convert just to a 'string' and split incoming strings for ',' to build your list of enums.